# How to convert string to byte in Visual Basic

Tags: vba

I'm trying to simulate an algoritham in cryptography and I need to convert a string of 0s and 1s back into a word. Example:
I have: 01011110010101101000001101100001101
I have split it into an array of strings:
0101111, 0010101, ...

each member has 7 characters. I want to get a letter that 0101111 represents in UTF8? How do I do this?

I try CType("0010101", Byte), but it fails. I can pass max 111 this way.
Help :/

Comment: Erm... shouldn't bytes be 8 bits instead of 7?

Comment: @DanielCook That might not work out so well. Every byte with an arbitrary 7-bit pattern (with a 0 msb) is a valid UTF-8 encoding with one byte per character. That's not true for arbitrary 8-bit patterns. One character set that would work for is CP437.

Comment: For what it's worth, with VB.NET and inefficient LINQ, I got zT␅6X. I didn't notice the [vba] until later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UTF-8 is 8 bit, those are only 7 bits. Do you mean 7 bit ASCII?

In that case here you go:

```
Function BinToStr(binStr As String) As String

    Dim i As Long

    For i = 0 To (Len(binStr) / 7) - 1
        [A1] = CLng(Mid(binStr, i * 7 + 1, 7))
        BinToStr = BinToStr & Chr([BIN2DEC(A1)])
    Next
End Function
```

If that's not what you're looking for, let me know.

Comment: What do the square brackets `[` `]` do ?

Comment: @ja72 That's built into Excel VBA as a quick way to access cell references and functions. He may not have even been asking for VBA, he may have meant VB.NET, in which case [A1] would just be replaced with a temporary variable and the BIN2DEC function would have to come from the VB.NET library.